# OpenMPI mpirun universe size

Tags: openmpi

I do not know if I perhaps understand this incorrectly. But here is what I want to achieve with OpenMPI in particular just starting with mpirun:

- I want to create a single process using the -np parameter that specifies the world size as 1
- I then want to set the universe size to some arbitrary number (for argument sake 10), how do I do this?

The following two commands:

- MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
- MPI_Attr_get(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE, &universe_size,
  &flag);

yield the output of `world_size` as 1 and `universe_size` as 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I found 2 ways of doing this:

- Implicit: mpirun -np 1 -H localhost,localhost,...,localhost executable
- Explicit: just assign a value to universe_size in the application itself, it will work fine.

Thank you for anyone that looked at this.

Comment: There should be a better way. For instance, in mpich (and its derivaties, such as Intel MPI) you can set an option on mpiexec:
https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Proposed_MPIEXEC_Extensions
Sorry, I don't speak OpenMPI, but I'm sure they have something similar.