# How do I find the number of cores available to MPI(4PY)?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi, mpi4py

How do I find the number of cores available to MPI(4PY)?

---

**Motivation**

My Python program spawns MPI instances hierarchically.

The first spawn always happens and creates 4 instances. It doesn't make sense to increase this number due to the structure of my computations, so I hardcoded it.

Depending on the command line options to the main program, each of the 4 instances then call external Python software that scales almost linearly.

I call this external software using

```
N=3
child=MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn(sys.executable,args=[`external.py`],maxprocs=N)
```

At the moment, I use `N=3` so that the 4 instances of the first spawn each spawn 3 instances of the external program, which yields  a total of 12 instances, matching the number of cores on my workstation.

However, for portability, I would like to do

```
N_avail = <MPI.N_CORES> #on my workstation: N_avail=12
N = N_avail/MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_size() #on my workstation: N=12/4=3
```

so that the number of available cores needn't be hardcoded.

Is this possible, and does it make sense?

---

**Notes**

I had hoped that not specifying maxprocs would do the job, just as `mpirun` with out `-np` spawns as many instances as available cores. However, `Spawn` then defaults to `maxprocs=1`.

The call of the external library is blocking, which is why I don't (wouldn't) subtract the 4 instances from the first spawn from `N_avail`.

I can't just use `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`, since this would only give me the cores on the current node (in a cluster setting). I am planning to run my code on a cluster using a SLURM scheduler.

Comment: if you are running under SLURM, then you can use `$SLURM_NTASKS` to figure out how many slots were allocated.

Answer (score 3):

There is an **attribute of the world communicator** that might provide the total number of process expected: **`MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE`**. See the MPI standards, http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node253.htm#Node253

> MPI provides an attribute on `MPI_COMM_WORLD`, `MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE`, that allows the application to obtain this information in a portable manner. This attribute indicates the total number of processes that are expected. ... An application typically subtracts the size of `MPI_COMM_WORLD` from `MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE` to find out how many processes it should spawn. ...

In mpi4py, it can be printed as:

```
from mpi4py import MPI

version= MPI.Get_version()
print "mpi version is ",version

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
print "size is ",size

universe_size=comm.Get_attr(MPI.UNIVERSE_SIZE)
print "universe size is ",universe_size
```

Following [OpenMPI mpirun universe size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585838/openmpi-mpirun-universe-size) , this feature can be tested by trying:

```
mpirun -np 1 -H localhost,localhost,localhost python main.py
```

**If your MPI version is higher or equal to 3, the MPI_Info [`MPI_INFO_ENV`](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node225.htm) could help you.** It features two keys which might provide some pieces of information:

> `maxprocs`   Maximum number of MPI processes to start.
>
> `soft`       Allowed values for number of processors.

To use it in mpi4py, you could try:

```
soft=MPI.INFO_ENV.get("soft")
print soft
maxprocs=MPI.INFO_ENV.get("maxprocs")
print maxprocs
```

Comment: First approach: This is able to reproduce the number of times I typed localhost. However, I would like to start `main.py` without mpirun and then figure out how many cores are available. Even if I start `mpirun -np 4 python main.py`, i.e. I dont use the `-H` flag, this approach always returns `1`

Comment: Second approach: Both return the argument passed to `-np` , or `1` if run without `mpirun`